# Is it posible to spellcheck and search in the same Solr request?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to do a spellcheck and a search (using topmost collated suggestion from the list) within a single Solr request?

I see that if my query is spelled correctly, I get search results returned.  But if the query is misspelled, I get suggestions and collations only.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 1) spellcheck.collate=true 2) behind the scenes analyze the collation and re-execute the query .
Documentation here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.collate